# Angular 2 prevent input inside component from firing form submit outside of the component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Outside form:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value, myForm.isValid)">
  <tags-input></tags-input>
</form>
```

Tags input component template:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newTag" (keyup.enter)="addTag(newTag, $event)">
```

Tags input component:

```
addTag(newTag: any, e: any) {

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Despite this, it still fires the submit in the outer form.

How can I prevent the form from submitting when I press enter in the input inside the component?

I'm thinking that there must be a way to achieve this with an `EventEmitter` or something, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Try to change `keyup` to `keydown`

Comment: @yurzui That doesn't work either. I found out that as soon as I add the tags-input component inside the form the whole form submit just stops working. It's like the component takes over the entire form, because I can't submit it outside of the component anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the keyup event will not prevent the submit event of the form. One way to solve it is to raise a flag on the parent component. Something like:

### Parent component

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value, myForm.isValid)">
  <tags-input (enter)="onEnter()"></tags-input>
</form>

onEnter() {
  this.preventSave = true;
}

save() {
  if (!this.preventSave) {
    // do save
  }
}
```

### Child component

```
@Output() enter = new EventEmitter();

addTag(newTag: any, e: any) {
  this.enter.emit();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```